# What is $G'(x)$ equal to if $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)x \,dt$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is a continuous, real-valued function defined on $[0,b]$, and $b >0$, then if $$G(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)x \,dt$$ for $0 \le x \le b$, what is $G'(x)$ equal to?

Comment: @coreyman317: If $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)x\sin(xt) \,dt$, then does $x$ act as a constant?

Comment: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: @coreyman317: so if we have that $g(t) = \sin(xt)$, then if $H(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) g(t) dt$, does $H'(x) = f(t)g(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment:

In general, if we have $$H(x)=\int_a^xg(x,t)dt$$

the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) says: $$H'(x)=g(x,x)+\int_a^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,t) dt $$

Thus if $j(x,t)=\sin(xt)$ and $H(x)=\int_0^xf(t)j(x,t)dt=\int_0^x\underbrace{f(t)\sin(xt)}_{g(x,t)}dt$

then by the Leibniz integral rule, $$H'(x)=f(x)\sin(x\cdot x)+\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f(t)\sin(xt)\right)dt$$
$$=f(x)\sin(x^2)+\int_0^xtf(t)\cos(xt)\space dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $ g:x\mapsto x $, and $ H:x\mapsto\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t} $, we have : $$ \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right),\ G\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)H\left(x\right) $$ Thus by the product rule : \begin{aligned}\left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right),\ G'\left(x\right)&=g'\left(x\right)H\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)H'\left(x\right) \\ &=\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}+xf\left(x\right)\end{aligned}

$\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}=\left(0,+\infty\right)\right) $

Comment: so if we have that $g(t) = \sin(xt)$, then if $H(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) g(t) dt$, does $H'(x) = f(t)g(t)$?

Comment: Well, your $ g $ is not a function of $ t $ only. You must denote $ g\left(x,t\right)=\sin{\left(xt\right)} $, since $ x $ and $ t $ both move. $ t $ is the integration variable and $ x $ is the differentiation variable. If you wanna differentiate $ \int\limits_{0}^{x}{f\left(t\right)g\left(x,t\right)\mathrm{d}t} $, apply a substitution to get $$ x\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(xt\right)g\left(x,xt\right)\mathrm{d}t} $$ then use the differentiation under the integral sign theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule
$$
G'(x) = xf(x) + \int^x_0 f
$$